# copy files with npm copyfiles to another directory

Tags: npm, create-react-app, file-copying

I want that in the end of my build script, the build folder will be copy to another location, so I tried using [copy-files-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles) -

```
"build": "react-scripts build && copyfiles build/*. out",
```

I was not able to figure out how to copy the entire build folder to another location, trying to specify the location like `C:/someLocaion/build2` will result in the console showing `SomeLocaion/build2`.

Comment: What does the current script produces?

Comment: creates a build folder, and nothing else.

Comment: Well, I ran the same script `react-scripts build && copyfiles build/* out` and it outputs `out/build/*` with the contents inside.

Comment: I am assuming you are using Windows. In that case the problem is with using `&&`. Use `&` instead.

Comment: The documentation shows only one.

Comment: @Abrar - The `&&` operator works perfectly ok in npm scripts for chaining tasks on Windows too. It's logic is analogous to Bash too, i.e. the command on the right will only execute if the command on the left exits successfully with a zero exit code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`copyfiles` didn't work for me on Windows. I've replaced it with [shx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shx), which is cross-platform. I'd also suggest to move the copy step to a separate script called `postbuild` (which will be ran [automatically](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) after the `build` script) for better separation of concerns:

```
"build": "react-scripts build",
"postbuild": "shx rm -rf out && shx cp -r build out",
```

Notice that I'm also wiping the target directory before copying the build artifacts there to avoid any leftovers from the previous build.